# While deleting file error occurs : Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, .net, file, delete-file

I am trying to delete File from the folder for which Full control is assigned but still sometime users get Access Denied for that folder.

This happens sometimes not every time.

Note : before deleting we check if file is in use. Following are two functions.

Delete File :

```
public static Boolean DeleteFile(string filePath)
{
    bool isFileInUse = false;
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
       FileInfo currentFileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
      if (!IsFileLocked(currentFileInfo))
         File.Delete(filePath);
      else
        isFileInUse = true;
    }
    return isFileInUse;
}
```

IsFileLocked :

```
private static Boolean IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
     FileStream stream = null;
     try
     {
         //Don't change FileAccess to ReadWrite, 
         //because if a file is in readOnly, it fails.
         stream = file.Open
         (
             FileMode.Open,
             FileAccess.Read,
             FileShare.None
         );
      }
      catch (IOException)
      {
          //the file is unavailable because it is:
          //still being written to
          //or being processed by another thread
          //or does not exist (has already been processed)
          return true;
       }
       finally
       {
           if (stream != null)
                    stream.Close();
       }

       //file is not locked
       return false;
}
```

Can anyone tell me even after giving full control why sometimes this error occurs ??

Note : We first need to check compulsory if file is in use while we try to delete it.

Comment: Is this happenig on a network drive? Could you determine who is putting the file there if he/she has more privileges than your app user?

Comment: Please give us the full Excpetion details. ex.ToString() is usually the quickest way to get that. | Checking if the file is locked or exists will not do you any good. You only run into a race condition that way. These kind of Exceptions are exogenous. You can not avoid them, only gracefully handle them: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: Why is this non-repro upvoted? I'm genuinely wondering what's happening with voting lately.

Comment: Why down vote the question? It's a good question and @Christopher referenced article is amazing.

Comment: @CodeCaster If you found a way to make File Access and similar local-only errors reproduceable, let us know. Till then - aside from lacking Exception details - this is aperfectly good question.

Comment: @Christopher there are thousands of questions about this exception, and the OP has to do the troubleshooting. All we can do is repeat what has been stated in previous questions.